How to get data from FastUI form
I have a router which produce form for uploading file
@router.get("/upload_data", response_model=FastUI, response_model_exclude_none=True)
def get_upload_data_page():
    return [
        c.Page(
            components=[
                c.Heading(text='Uploaddata', level=2),
                c.Form(
                    submit_url='/api/process_data',
                    form_fields=[c.FormFieldFile(name='filefield', title='')]
                )
            ]
        ),
        tmp
    ]

How can I get file which uploaded to this form in other router "/process_data"? What should be inside function arguments?
@router.post("/process_data")
def validate_uploaded_data():

    return [c.FireEvent(event=GoToEvent(url='/'))]

I also tried make form by ModelForm, but file which comes to post router comes closed and I can`t read it. Maybe there is some way to reopen file or make come to router not closed?
Will be grateful to any suggestion

try this
from starlette.datastructures import UploadFile    
def get_upload_data_page(file: UploadFile)

